# Attached PDF file(in Japanese) damaged after uploaded via VPN

Tags: pdf, upload, vpn

We are currently working with an IBM workflow application called FormWave and 
running an electronic approval system.
Currently we are working at home and using VPN((wifi at home).
We are struggling with the investigation because there is a problem that the file is damaged when uploaded via VPN.
Corruption means that when viewed with a binary editor, some data becomes zero bytes.

**-Environment and Conditions**

・App: IBM FormWave for WebSphere 6.1.2.3

・Middle: IBM WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.13

・DB: IBM DB2 9.7.3

・OS: IBM AIX 6.1 TL7 SP6

・VPN: 2 channels(VPN1, VPN2) via wifi at home

***Not occur**

・Internal network(company)

・Tethering(via VPN) from iPhone which is provided by company

**-Steps**

① Convert to PDF file written in Japanese on PC

② Save the PDF file as an attached file to the electronic approval that is connected by vpn

③ Download the file saved in electronic approval on your PC

**-Problems**

When opening the file attached to the electronic approval via VPN(wifi), the following events occur.

・Color unevenness of image data (ex. the background becomes greenish)

・Characters are faint

・Font cannot be read and characters are not displayed.

・Error displayed when opening a file

・occurs only at PDF files and other files like Excel, word are displayed correctly.

We thinks this might be a rare phenomenon in which the TCP layer affects upper layers with the result of error.
We found large sized files may occur events more frequently than small sized files.
What could be the cause?

Any help would be appreciated.

-The image is binary data comparison.

left is original and right is uploaded file.
blue parts are turned to red parts(00 byte)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you yet analyzed how exactly the file is damaged? E.g. have you done a binary compare of a file retrieved via vpn2 with the original? The symptoms might be an effect of some component you use treating the pdf as text data, not binary data.

Comment: yes. we compared the original and uploaded files and you can check the comparison image. I just uploaded it.

Comment: Is that the only difference or is that an example and there are multiple such differences in there file?

Comment: thanks for the reply.
there some more differences and I uploaded images. and we found that the other VPN also occurs events. so all VPN connections have a problem.

Comment: Replacement by zeros is not the usual result of binary data incorrectly handled as text as I first assumed, replacement by the so-called *replacement character* would be. Thus, apparently some program in your setup replaces bytes. Have you checked whether for different files it is at the same position or for similar original byte sequences? Is there probably some virus scanner involved that replaces certain byte sequences in an attempt to stop viruses?

Comment: Alternatively, do you have some web proxy (caching or filtering) in place for the people accessing the application from home? A caching proxy (if incorrectly configured or broken) might mix different contents for the same URL accessed by different people. A filtering proxy (if incorrectly configured or broken) might do replacements meant for other file types incorrectly for these PDF files, too. If there is a proxy, try not to use it (your company firewalls may have to be reconfigured for that).

Comment: I do not know whether there is a proxy or not. After testing uploading different sized files we found that large sized files have more possibility to occur events than small ones. Especially small sized files do not occur events.
I just wonder why there is no problem when we are using the internal network.

Comment: *"I just wonder why there is no problem when we are using the internal network."* - That's why I would think of stuff like proxies and virus scanners which might differ for/on external computers compared to internal ones. By the way, are the documents transferred via TLS secured connections (https or similar) or as plain content (http or similar)?

Comment: There is the OfficeScan installed on client PC(Windows10) but I heard that scanning for HTTP and HTTPS routes is disabled.And If this were a problem, the same problem occur with internal network that never return a VPN.

Comment: The internal network that does not go through the proxy but we don't know about the VPN environment so we need to check. We are using HTTP.

Comment: "The symptoms might be an effect of some component you use treating the pdf as text data, not binary data."-I wonder what the components are. Do you mean clients components or server side ones.(pdf converters, middleware, application, etc.)

Comment: I meant any component involved in the pdf transfer. But as I mentioned later, replacement by zeros is not typical for text/binary issues.

Comment: thanks for the reply. we investigated the VPN1&2 then we found that there is no difference. According to proxy we don't use proxy to access to the internal system via VPN. Only use proxy to access to the internet via VPN. This event occurred in the internal system,

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid I'm out of concrete ideas. You should probably take tcp dumps, starting at the app server and the external client, and if you see that contents differ between those stages, also on other stations in-between, to determine where the change occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We are still investigating this failure but your advice is very helpful. 
We found There is regularity in the place where the replacement by zero occurs.

Comment: Although it is different from the replacement part, 
it has the common point that the size of the replaced data is always 5 bytes.
There are cases where replacement occurs with less than 5 bytes
but it occurs when the data before replacement was originally zero. 
The TCP dump has not been done yet.